# I'm not able to login using PHP (pdo) & AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

I'm using framework 7, I'm trying to login using PHP (PDO) and Ajax however, every time it comes up with "login failed" even if the correct data was inserted in the email and password inputs, also no error is coming up, I was able to register using PHP (PDO) and everything is going just fine, but not able to login at all, please advise what's wrong with my code

```
index.php

<div class="pages navbar-through" class="login-screen">
<div data-page="index" class="page no-navbar no-toolbar">
<div class="page-content" style="background:url(img/bg1.png) ;background-
size: 100%">
<div class="content-block-title center">
</div>


<span style="float: right;color: white;margin:20px;font-size: 20px">
<b>عربي</b></span>


<div class="list-block" style="margin:100px 70px auto 70px;">

<img src="img/logo2.png" style="height: 55px ;width: 100%;margin-bottom: 
60px;text-align: center;">
<div class="item-input" style="border-bottom: 1px solid gray">
<input type="text"  placeholder="Email" id="email" name="email" style="font-
size: 15px;color: white;" required>
</div>

<div class="item-input" style="border-bottom: 1px solid gray;margin-top: 
10px">
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" id="password" 
style="font-size: 15px;color: white"; required>
</div>



<div style="text-align: center ;margin-top: 30px"> 
<a href="#" style="color:  #00bcd4 ;font-size: 15px">Forgot your password ?
</a>
<span id="login_message"><img src="img/ajax-loader.gif" style="display: 
none;"></span>

<center><button style="margin-top: 20px; background-color:  #00bcd4;border-
radius: 0px;height: 45px; width: 240px; color: white; text-align: center;" 
name="login-btn" class="list-button" id="login-btn" name="login-btn">Login</button></center>



<p style="color: white;font-size: 13px;margin-top: 40px"> You don't have 
account? </p> 
<a href="registeration.php" style="color: #ffeb3b ;font-size: 
13px">REGISTER</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

my-App.js

$(document).ready(function() {
$('#login-btn').click(function () {
var email = $('#email').val();
var password = $('#password').val();

if($.trim(email).length > 0 && $.trim(password).length > 0)
{
$.ajax({
url:"login.php",
method: "POST",
data: {email:email, password:password},
cache: false,
beforeSend:function()
{
$('#login-btn').val("connecting...");
},
success:function(data){
if(data){
myApp.alert('Login successful');
}
else{
myApp.alert('Login failed');
}
}
});
}
});
});

 login.php

<?php
require_once 'config.php';
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['login-btn'])){
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$select = $db_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE email='$email' and 
password='$password'");
$select->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$select->execute();
$data=$select->fetch();
if($data['email']!=$email and $data['password']!=$pass)
{
echo "invalid email or password";
}
elseif($data['email']==$email and $data['pass']==$pass)
{
$_SESSION['email']=$data['email'];
echo "successful"; 
}
}
?>
```

Comment: You `prepare` a query then fail to `bindParam` on it, making `prepare` pointless. Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: If you're going to ask for help, at least make a minimal effort and align your code properly

Comment: `if(isset($_POST['login-btn'])){` - you did not send a parameter named `login-btn` with your AJAX request, so this will always be false ...

Comment: And you managed to still enable SQL injection with “prepared” statements ...

Answer (score 2):

Your `login.php` file has this check before attempting to log in:

```
if(isset($_POST['login-btn'])){
```

However, your AJAX script does not send a value called "login-btn", only a value called "email" and a value called "password":

```
data: {email:email, password:password},
```

If you change your `if` statement to check for `$_POST['email']` instead, it should work, assuming there are no other problems.

Please also note that your query is vulnerable to SQL injection. Please use bound parameters instead of using your variables directly in your query:

```
$select = $db_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE email=:email and password=:password");
$select->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$select->execute(array(':email' => $email, ':password' => $password);
```

Comment: I've changed if(isset($_POST['login-btn'])){ to $_POST['email'], now it's always coming up with login successful even if the credentials are not correct.

Comment: That's because your javascript success handler only checks `if(data){`, since `data` is a string (the string echo'd from PHP) it will always be `true`

Comment: do you have any suggesstions ?

Comment: Dude thank you so much for your help, it's working perfectly now, and regarding SQWL injection, I'm testing localhost ad not done with the code. thanks for the advice though :)